# How to create an Asymmetric Layout on Android

Tags: android, listview, gridview, grid-layout

How to create an asymmetric layout similar to the image attached? The standard android guides show only how to create symmetric Lists and Tables

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the comment @DerGolem can you give me a sample code...

Comment: Here's a nice tutorial on ListViews: http://chrisrisner.com/31-Days-of-Android--Day-20%E2%80%93ListViews. Just modify it to insert alternate row layouts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [AsymmetricGridView](https://github.com/felipecsl/AsymmetricGridView). The GridView does not support having that. You can use GridLayout to achieve this but it does not use AbsListView and you can't use recycling.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make a left-aligned (big picture on left) and right-aligned (big picture on right) XML layout for the rows. Each has a horizontal ListView containing the big picture (on left or right) and another vertical ListView containing the small pictures.
2. In the adapter for your ListView choose either the right- or left-aligned layout based on whether position is odd or even with (something like):

   ```
   @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

   View rowView = convertView;

   //Reuse views.
   LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
           .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
   if (rowView == null && (position % 2) == 0 //even position) {
       rowView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.your_right_aligned_layout, parent, false); }
   else if (rowView == null && (position % 2) != 0 //odd position){
       rowView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.your_left_aligned_layout, parent, false); }
   ...
   ```